# How does google check refresh token - client binding for their OAuth 2.0?

Tags: android, ios, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

OAuth 2.0 protocol says

"The authorization server MUST verify the binding between the refresh token and client identity whenever the client identity can be authenticated."

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.4

I'm interested how they check the "refresh token - client binding" for Android and IOS apps? How do they know that the request came from the app that generated the refresh token and not some other app (this when the refresh token is presented in order to get a new access-token)?

What do you think is the best way to check "refresh token - client" binding ?

Answer (score 2):

The client has to include client_id and client_secret in the request when exchanging the refresh token (see [docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp#refresh)). This authenticates the client and allows the server to verify that the refresh token is indeed bound to the client making the request before issuing an access token.

Comment: Yes, that's true...but if someone is able to steal the refresh token I'm sure it is able to steal the client_id and client_secret as well.

I think if you use Google's Android OAuth SDK they will include the app signature and check it against the server (the app must be signed before making it available in the store)